# How can I delete a specific line from a txt file based on user input?

Tags: python

How do I go about deleting a specific line in a text file that is based on the user input?

```
def remove():
    delete_value = input("Enter the value you wish to delete: ")

    with open("values.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    with open("values.txt", "w") as f:
        for line in lines:
            if line.strip("\n") != delete_animal:
                 f.write(line)
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: An exception in this is if the user inputs an animal that is not there, what will happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def remove():
    delete_value = input("Enter the value you wish to delete: ")

    with open("value.txt", "r") as f:
        file = f.readlines()
    with open("value.txt", "w") as f:
        for line in file:
            # we will skip the line that contains our target word
            # in this case the delete_animal
            words = line.strip("\n").lower().split(' ')
            if delete_value.lower() not in words:
                f.write(line)
```

**Input file:**

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
may name is sudipto
my name is sudiptoandiloveprogramming

user input: sudipto
```

**Output file after delete:**

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
my name is sudiptoandiloveprogramming
```

Comment: For some reason, the lines that got deleted were 1, 2, 6, 7 and 9 when I used this? I am also trying to get the "name" of the animal as a string input to delete it rather than a numbered line as it's unknown information to the user.

Comment: a lot of other lines get deleted while using this

Comment: Hey If you have `Tarantula` in the file, you have to input `Tarantula` to get the line deleted.  The code was not case insensitive. However, I now added case insensitivity. Please try again.

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
def remove():
    num = []
   
    delete_animal = input("Enter the name of the animal you wish to delete: ")
    file = open("txt file", "r")
    file.seek(0)
    list_of_lines = file.readlines()
    file.seek(0)
    lines = file.read().splitlines()
    file.close()
    if delete_animal not in lines:
        print("That line does not exist, please try again")
   

    for word in lines:
        num.append(0)
    
    if delete_animal == word:
        file = open('txt file','w')
        list_of_lines[len(num)-1] = ""
        file.writelines(list_of_lines)
        print('Animal Deleted')
```

This should delete the line in which the input animal is there

**EDIT**-
It should be `A3_s3902169_stock.txt`. You need to add that extension `.txt`

Comment: I'm afraid the code is still not deleting the "Tarantula" line